# How to avoid saving report output version in cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I am working on cognos and user wants that the output version of report is not saved with report.

I looked for options and found below screen that has radio button making it impossible to uncheck. Setting value to zero means unlimited number of output.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is default setting in Cognos that can be accessed from report properties.
It allows us to set the default action when user click on report link in Cognos connection.
As in below screen, I have set default action to run the report that was earlier view most recent report.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting Duration to 0 days will stop output versions being saved.

If not, set it to 1 day and it will clear itself each night.